# Jerky scrolling on flash (safari 5.0.5 and firefox 9.0.1)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, scroll, trackpad

I am creating a simple application in as3 that contains a Container with vertical scroll bar. I am running that sample on Firefox 9.0.1 and flash player is 11.1.102.55 and m using macbook pro LION.

Now the issue is while scrolling through trackpad it gives jerks. Its not smooth scroll. If i use mouse to scroll it works fine. Any idea how to re-solve it?

Comment: Can you share running example to properly understand "jerkiness"?

Comment: http://megaswf.com/serve/2283420
Use firefox 9.0.1 or safari 5.0.5
Try to scroll to top and further top. You will see jerkiness

Comment: Safari 5.1.2 looks OK, so I guess this is browser-to-mouseevents issue.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening would due to the properties of the scroll. The arrow up and down are basicaly re-accuring :

```
myMovieClip.y + height of the actual text;
```

So the above would will keep looping that function to say when the down arrow is pressed giving a jerky impression.take in mind the scroller properties is not scrolling 1 pixel but maybe 8 pixels at a time.depending on your text size it will scroll a line hieght.

```
MyMovieClip.y +=1;
```

Should be more fluent.
A better solution for complete smooth text scrolling would to be make your own scroller and use "BLITMASK" in your project file

To answer the other part of your question the mouse moving the scroller is smooth as it is constantly updating the position of the inner text area to the little slider thing.